# DevExpress WinForm TabPane Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am facing a weried problem with the TabPane control of the DevExpress for WinForms. I have an outer TabControl and now i have two differnt TabPane(DevExpress Control) on two different tabs of the Outer TabControl.

When I click on the First TabPane navigation. It jumps to the 2nd TabPane Control.

Please check the attached image and Let me know what i am doing wrong here.[image]

Comment: Better to ask this question in [DevExpress Forums](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create). They can give the best support.

Comment: @User6667769 thanks,  just created a ticket over there.